# Why does Laravel group RESTful methods the way they do?

Tags: laravel

I'm brand new to Laravel and am working my way through the [Laravel 6 from Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/33?autoplay=true) course over at Laracasts. The course is free but I can't afford a Laracasts membership so I can't ask questions there.

I've finished the first several sections of the course and am a little confused about some of the concepts around the whole RESTful idea. The instructor, who seems very good and experienced with Laravel, describes 7 methods that are going to be part of pretty much any CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) application (and most applications are CRUD in nature.) He says naming of these 7 methods should be consistent with this:

1. index - a list of all the resources in a collection e.g. all articles in a blog
2. show - display a specific resource from a collection e.g. a specific article in a blog
3. create - create a new instance of a resource e.g. add a new article to a blog
4. store - save a new instance of a resource to a data store like a database
5. edit - modify the contents of an existing resource e.g. change the title of an article
6. update - save the modified resource to a data store
7. destroy - remove a resource from a collection e.g. delete a blog article

I'm a little puzzled by this division of work into 7 separate methods. It seems to me that Create and Store belong together in a single method; ditto for Edit and Update. Creating a new record has two phases: displaying an empty form to gather up the data needed to construct a new article, then validating the data and storing it on the database. By the same token, changing an existing record consists of two phases: displaying the current data in a form and letting the user change what needs changing, then validating it and sending it to the database (or back to the user for corrections).

I would also argue that to be consistent with the approach they've used for create/store and edit/update, destroy should be divided into two methods, Destroy and Remove, where Destroy displays the full record that the user wants to remove with two buttons at the bottom: Delete and Cancel. Then, if the user clicks on Delete, they go to a Remove method that actually deletes the record f from the database.

I've been coding for a fair while and I've never seen a system where the user was allowed to delete any important record without first being shown the record and being asked if they're sure they want to delete it. Now, maybe that's fallen out of fashion and I didn't notice but it seems a pretty prudent thing to do.

So why are the methods what they are, at least as RESTful is implemented in Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to me that Create and Store belong together in a single method

Well, Laravel generate all those methods thinking in a server-side rendered app. So in a SSR, before you store your data, you must be able to see a creation form.. that's why this `create()` function exists. The `create()`, normally, should return a view that will show the user the valid fields to create a resource, this is all done in a `GET` request. Then, when the users hit the "create"/"add" button, it will reach the `store()` method that will implement the logic to persist this data storing a new record in your database, this is done in a `POST` request.

The same goes for `edit()`/`update()`.

> I've been coding for a fair while and I've never seen a system where the user was allowed to delete any important record without first being shown the record and being asked if they're sure they want to delete it

That is because those validations are commonly implemented in the client-side, so, you do this with JS in  your front-end, for validations of that kind you shouldn't hit the server.

> So why are the methods what they are, at least as RESTful is implemented in Laravel?

Finally, for a RESTful API you don't need all of those methods. Just `index`, `show`, `store`, `update` and `delete` ones. If you just need this kind of methods in your controller, you could exclude the `create`/`edit` ones by adding the `--api` flag when creating your controller through Artisan. From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes):

> #### API Resource Routes
>
> // ...
>
> To quickly generate an API resource controller that does not include the `create` or `edit` methods, use the `--api` switch when executing the `make:controller` command:
>
> ```
> php artisan make:controller API/PhotoController --api
> ```

Comment: Thanks for that insight, Kenny. It makes sense that the "are you sure?" part of the delete is at the client side and the server would only handle the physical deletion from the database. The rest of what you said makes sense too. Thanks again.

Comment: @Henry Delete method (or destroy route if you wish) serves just that: deletes particular record. It is up to you (developer) to authorize access to that route. You can check [gates and policies](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#via-controller-helpers) (via controller method is most concise way) of how efficiently set restrictions for some (or all) routes. Let's say you have entity table (let's call those products) and you don't want anyone but admin mess with those. You'd like to set policy that allows admin only to destroy/delete product (basically access that route).

Comment: @Tpojka - The course I'm taking hasn't gotten as far as gates and policies yet so I'll probably learn those things soon. I know this will be important since there could easily be material that only administrators should be able to delete so I'm going to need to know those things. Thanks for the link!